# How do I implement Naive Bayes on the following data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, anaconda

My data is in a csv file in the following form:

```
45,45,34,34,34,56,52,88,50,46,46,1

28,26,23,22,32,36,21,18,8,28,40,0

28,46,57,42,46,51,48,48,40,46,34,1

11,11,11,34,17,13,11,46,11,33,40,0

42,36,46,32,28,51,48,56,38,46,40,1
```

and so on.

I am trying to use a binary classifier where it can classify the data given as input as shown in the first 11 columns and the 12th column represents an acceptance(1) or rejection(0). I am using the pandas, numpy modules of python. How can I implement a Naive Bayes on the data?

I am getting a data conversion error:

```
 ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv')
features=df.values[:,:11]
target=df.values[:,12]

features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = 
train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 10)

clf=GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, target_train)
target_pred = clf.predict(features_test)
```

Comment: if you have an error resulting from your code then include all your code that produces this error. We don't have access to your computer. Please include your code that loads this csv, your code that tries to train/fit on this data etc..

Comment: Also, the first row has an empty cell in position 1. `float('')` fails.

Comment: @EdChum Added the code

Comment: @Kendas fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the csv in incorrectly, you need to do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, header=None)
```

you have a space in-between the comma separators, also you have no header row, this will yield:

```
Out[18]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0  45  45  34  34  34  56  52  88  50  46  46   1
1  28  26  23  22  32  36  21  18   8  28  40   0
2  28  46  57  42  46  51  48  48  40  46  34   1
```

and the dtypes are now numeric:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 12 columns):
0     3 non-null int64
1     3 non-null int64
2     3 non-null int64
3     3 non-null int64
4     3 non-null int64
5     3 non-null int64
6     3 non-null int64
7     3 non-null int64
8     3 non-null int64
9     3 non-null int64
10    3 non-null int64
11    3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(12)
memory usage: 368.0 bytes
```

Comment: I am getting total 1 column on using df.info()

Comment: Edit your question with a real representation of your data or a link to it, I can only advise on what is posted

Comment: Fixed it. Now the data does not have any space after the commas,

Comment: can you try just loading this using `numpy`: `df = np.loadtxt(r'file.csv', delimeter=',')`